# Button does not want to stop being visible

Tags: c#, winforms, button, screenshot, visibility

So, I'm trying to make simple screenshot app in Window Forms, but i would like my button to dissapear whenever I take a shot. Unfortunately, it does not want to be invisible, even after setting Visible to false:

```
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BackColor = Color.Red;
            this.TransparencyKey = BackColor;
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        }

        Image tmp = Image.FromFile("C:/Users/Bartek/source/repos/Hadr/Hadr/Image/image.png");

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(tmp.Width, tmp.Height);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            button1.Visible = false;
            g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size);
            pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
            bmp.Save("C:/Folder/image1.png",System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        }
```

I have set dock on picturebox to fill, and placed button in the way showed on screen:
[image]

I'm kindly asking for help

Comment: As a hack that you should never use, you could add a call to ```Application.DoEvents()``` after setting ```button1.Visible = false```.

Comment: Just a guess but usually generated click events do not include _1 `button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)` is usually `button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Comment: You have to exit the handler before the change to Visible will take effect. Because of that everything needed to take the screenshot should not happen in that event handler. Post a message instead, then react to that message to grab the screenshot.

Comment: Can't recreate it with the posted code.  My image does not show a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide the button first and then use BeginInvoke() to defer making the screenshot until the system updates controls, like this:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Visible = false;
    BeginInvoke(MakeScreenShot);
}

void MakeScreenshot()
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(tmp.Width, tmp.Height);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size);
    pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
    bmp.Save("C:/Folder/image1.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    
    button1.Visible = true;
}
```